# Passing Critera to PHP

Tags: php, sql, url, header, get

I am making a website where a user can create an account and then log in. Once logged in the user should be able to change the information they registered with.

When the user logs in their username is passed in the URL like below:

```
header("Location: loggedon.php?$username");
```

Now, on my loggedon.php page I have added this:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET["username"];
$query="SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username=['$username']"; 
$result = mysql_query ($query) or die ("error in query"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
// Print one row of results 
print "<tr>" . 
"<td>" . $row["CustomerID"] . "</td>" . 
"<td>" . $row["Firstnames"] . "</td>" . 
"<td>" . $row["Surname"] . "</td>" . 
"<td>" . $row["Username"] . "</td>" . 
"<td>" . $row["Email"] . "</td>" .
"<td>" . $row["Password"] . "</td>" .
//print a change/delete link at the end of each row
                "<td><a href=customerChangeDelete.php?id=".$row['CustomerID'].">Change/Delete</a></td>";                    
print "</tr>"; 
} 
// Then, finish the table
print "</table>";
}
?>
```

When I run the page and log in I get the following errors:

Notice: Undefined index: username in J:\xampp\htdocs\loggedon.php on line 60

error in query

I presume I have made some sort of mistake when trying to extract the username from the URL (?). If anyone could please give me a push in the right direction that would be amazing. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how your application looks like, but maybe you want to think about some security related things. GET and POST parameters are very insecure because the user can manipulate it. Someone may call loggedon.php?username=administrator and see things that he should not see. Maybe you posted a reduced example, but I don't see any verification if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#example-1528)? It would be safer.

In other hand with "Location: loggedon.php?$username" you are getting an url like:

loggedon.php?john

but, for $_GET you should get a url like:

loggedon.php?username=john

I recommend you change

```
header("Location: loggedon.php?$username");
```

with:

```
header("Location: loggedon.php?username=".$username);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not name the username-Parameter in your header redirect. Use

```
header("Location: loggedon.php?username=$username");
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately I still get the 'Error in query' message, and no data from the DB.

Comment: sorry, missed that message. Galled posted an answer which mentions mysql_real_esacape_string. Take a look at this. In the linked manual are some good examples. Basically you have an syntax error because of the brackets. "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE username='$username'" would work, but is --very-- insecure.

Comment: Thanks, ill take a look now! At the moment im trying to work on the foundations/basics really, going to be looking at the security side in a couple of weeks =)

Comment: Ok, but do not miss the security things ;) Please don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem. IMHO Galled had the right answers.